# Python regex for string with optional part in Django RegexField

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm striving with getting the regex right. I want to match the strings like 'pci0000_00_0b_0' and 'bus1port1' with optional '-[somedigit]', like pci0000_00_0b_0-4 or bus1port1-0.

Here's the regex:

```
device_re = re.compile(r'(pci[0-9a-f]{4}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{1}(-\d+)?)|(bus\d+port\d+(-\d+)?)')
```

Unfortunately when I create the Django Field inherited from RegexField:

```
forms.RegexField.__init__(self, device_re,
                                  max_length, min_length, *args, **kwargs)
```

unfortunately, it also matches pci0000_00_0b-whatever , pci0000_00_0bwhatever ... 
Additionaly, could anyone give me a tips how RegexField uses given regex ?

Comment: is this part `pci0000_00_0b_0` compulsory if yes the you remove the last `_0` in your example?

Comment: I forgot about that '_0' . fixed. This part is compulsory

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would make the last `-\d+` part as optional.

```
^(?:pci[0-9a-f]{4}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{1}|bus\d+port\d+)(?:-\d+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sS5aN5/1)

If you want only one digit after `-`, then remove the `+` mark from the `\d` in the optional part.

```
^(?:pci[0-9a-f]{4}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{1}|bus\d+port\d+)(?:-\d)?$
```

Comment: It still matches partly for 'pci0000_00_0b_0-c' in example, causing the RegexField in Django to claim this as valid. But if I add ^ at the beginning and $ at the end it works properly.

so this version works as expected:
`r'^(?:pci[0-9a-f]{4}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{2}_[0-9a-f]{1}|bus\d+port\d+)(?:-\d+)?$'`